# KendoUI slider doesn't work in kendoUI view

Tags: view, slider, kendo-ui

I have such a sample code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.1.319/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.1.319/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.1.319/js/kendo.web.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="ppp">
  </div>
  <script id="conf_ppp" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <input data-role="slider"/>
  </script>
  <script>
    var p = new kendo.View("conf_ppp");
    p.render("#ppp");
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The "slider" can't be rendered properly. Anybody can help on this?

Answer (score 0):

You are using an old version which doesn't include Kendo SPA. You need at least 2013.1.319:

```
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.1.319/js/kendo.web.min.js"></script>
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/esokep/1/edit) is a live demo

Comment: Even changing to 2013.1.319, it still has problem. Just in your live demo, the slider can't slide.